# Is there a better way to design this quiz?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just programmed a quiz and the code is given below. Is there a better way to program to do what I have done?  Also I tried to do transition effect while the question is changing, but it isn't working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Quiz</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css">
    <style type="text/css">
                    body {
                        background-color: black;
                        margin: 0;
                    }

                    div img {
                        position: fixed;
                        height: 25%;
                        width: 15%;
                        top: 1%;
                        opacity: .9;
                    }

                    .container {
                        margin: auto;
                        text-align: center;
                        background-color: white;
                        width: 60%;
                        margin-top: 10%;
                        border-radius: 3%;
                        transition: all 5s;
                        -webkit-transition: all 5s;
                    }

                    #quest {
                        font-size: 20px;
                        padding-top: 3%;
                        padding-bottom: 2%;
                        border-bottom: dashed black 2px;

                    }

                    #choi {
                        padding-top: 3%;
                        text-align: left;
                    }

                    li {
                        padding-top: 1%;
                        padding-left: 5%;

                    }

                    #button input {
                        margin-top: 2%;
                        margin-bottom: 2%;
                        padding: 1%;
                        background-color: #3498DB;
                        border-radius: 40%;
                        color: white;
                    }

                    #button input:hover {
                        color: #7F7F7F;
                        cursor: pointer;
                    }


    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="answer"></div>
        <div id="quest"></div>
        <div id="choi"></div>
        <div id="button"></div>
        <div id="selectOne"></div>
        <script src="quiz.js"></script>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
                var questions = ["How many letters does 'quiz' have??", "where is karnataka??", "Where is India??"];
                var options = [[ 5 , 4 , 2 ],["India","America"],["africa","antarctica","asia"]];
                var answer = [4,"India","asia"];
                var noOfQues = questions.length;
                var div = document.getElementById("quest");
                var i = 0;
                var marks = 0;
                var continuousCorrect = 0;
                var nextClickCount = 0;
                appendList();

                function ques() {

                    // Checking if one of the choices is selected
                    for (var h = 0; h < document.getElementById("choi").childNodes.length; h++) {


                        if (document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[h].checked == true) {
                            // Comparing the selected choice with the right answer
                            if (answer[i] == document.getElementById("choi").childNodes[h].textContent) {
                                continuousCorrect++;
                                marks = marks + ( continuousCorrect * 10 );
                                document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "The answer is right and your total score is " + marks ;
                                document.getElementById("answer").style.color="green";
                            } 
                            else{
                                continuousCorrect = 0;
                                marks = marks + (continuousCorrect * 10);
                                document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "The answer is wrong. The right answer is " + answer[i] + ". And Your total score is " + marks ;
                                document.getElementById("answer").style.color="red";
                            };

                            document.getElementById("button").removeChild(document.getElementById("button").childNodes[0]);
                            opti();



                            var check = "yes";
                        };
                        if (check!== "yes") {
                            document.getElementById("selectOne").innerHTML = "Select one of the answers given";
                        };
                    };


                }

                function appendList() {
                    div.innerHTML = questions[i];
                    var noOfChoi = options[i].length;
                    // Remove "Select one of the choices message"
                    document.getElementById("selectOne").innerHTML = "";
                    // Creating Next Button
                    var creButton = document.createElement("INPUT");
                    creButton.setAttribute("type","button");
                    creButton.setAttribute("onclick","ques()");
                    creButton.setAttribute("value","Next");
                    document.getElementById("button").appendChild(creButton);
                for (var k = 0 ; k < noOfChoi ; k++) {

                        // Inserting options
                        var node = document.createElement("INPUT");
                        node.setAttribute("type", "radio");
                        node.setAttribute("name", "x"); // To make only one radio button active
                        var list = document.createElement("LI");
                        var textnode = document.createTextNode(options[i][k]);
                        list.appendChild(node);
                        list.appendChild(textnode);
                        document.getElementById("choi").appendChild(list);
                    };
                }

                function opti() {
                    // To update the choice by removing the old items
                    var noofthings = document.getElementById("choi").childNodes.length;
                    for (var j = 0; j < noofthings; j++) {
                        document.getElementById("choi").removeChild(document.getElementById("choi").childNodes[0]);
                    };


                    // To update the choice by adding choices corresponding to the question
                    i = i+1;
                    if(i >= noOfQues){
                            div.innerHTML = "This is the end of the quiz";
                            document.getElementById("choi").innerHTML = "";
                            // Remove "Select one of the choices message"
                            document.getElementById("selectOne").innerHTML = "";
                    }
                    else {
                            appendList();

                    }
                }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Be aware that we cannot help you with the non-working transition effect.  Such questions belong on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Can you create a working demo for us?

Comment: This is the link to the working demo: http://www.codecademy.com/betaSolver43508/codebits/N08En8

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Overview

**Overall, this code looks moderately well written, albeit with questionable formatting.** I'm going to suggest some formatting methods that aren't necessarily best practice, but will improve the look and readability of your code. I'll also be making a suggestion or two on your method of defining and storing data.

---

### Formatting

**Line Width**

> ```
> document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "The answer is right and your total score is " + marks ;
> ```

This line runs a long way to the right forcing you to scroll back and forth to edit code in smaller editor views.

Example:

```
 var successMessage = "The answer is right and your total score is ";
 document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = successMessage + marks ;
```

**Character Spacing**

> ```
> document.getElementById("answer").style.color="green";
> ```

In the other line, you space the = sign with 1 space of padding. Figure out which method works for you, and stick with it.

**I prefer to pad my functions**

By padding the interior of a function's brackets with blank lines, you achieve a more readable result, in my humble opinion.

Instead of:

```
function doStuff() {
    //do stuff
}
```

Try this:

```
function doStuff() {

    //do stuff

}
```

It'll make your code taller, but much nicer to read in my opinion.

---

### Defining and Storing Data

Rather than "hard-coding" your data (messages, questions, answers) into your code, and into arrays, I suggest starting the arrays off empty, and using a function to dynamically add additional values. That way, it becomes a much neater process to extend your quiz.

Example:

```
function addQuestion(question, answer){

    //append values to array

}
```

---

### JavaScript Coding Practices

First of all, [read this great answer on Programmers SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/180588/139797), explaining the many ways that you can improve the quality of your JavaScript with popular patterns and Object Oriented practices.

**Single Function Function**

Let's apply the *Single Function Function* principle to your code.

From the answer cited above:

> Instead of having a huge mess of callback hell, **keep a single function
>   to a single task, and do that task well.** Sometimes you can get ahead
>   of yourself and add more functionality within each function, but ask
>   yourself: Can this become an independent function? Name the function,
>   and this cleans up your indentation and, as a result, cleans up the
>   callback hell problem.

Now, while this is toned towards callbacks, *Single Function Function* is not a principle designed to prevent callback hell, specifically. That's just one effect.

By keeping everything separated into one-job functions, you end up with loosely coupled (Decoupled) code.

> Decoupling refers to careful controls that separate code modules from
>   particular use cases, which increases code re-usability. -Wikipedia

Try breaking down your `ques()` function's contents into their own, smaller functions, and call them within.

*That's as far as we'll go this time. If you choose to re-write the quiz, and post your improved code, I'd focus on explaining how you might write it in an Object Oriented manner.*